# Broken icon in the applications folder in the dock

Tags: macos

I downloaded an application and copied it to the Applications folder.  When I click on the Applications folder in the dock, the icon for this program is broken. It runs fine, and if I create a direct shortcut to the application on the dock, the icon here is fine.

Any ideas why the icon would be broken within the applications folder in the dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual behavior for Applications that you newly installed from the internet (not with the Mac App Store).

You should also be asked whether you are sure to open it because it has been downloaded from the internet.

After a restart, or perhaps just logging out and in again, the usual icon should appear.

Comment: OK...are you implying that at some future point the icon will appear normally?

Comment: Yes, log out and in again or restart the computer.